# Want to get rid of the control from the LDAP response in linux machine

Tags: java, ldap, unboundid-ldap-sdk

We are using unboundid-ldapsdk library for our project ,in the response we are getting the control as inbound character in the Ldap response example as:-

```
Example of Ldap Response :-
Query:
 ldapsearch -D "cn=Directory Manager" -w dsfdsdf -h localhost -p 8080 
-x -b  "dc=example,dc=com"  "(userid=2)"


Response:

# extended LDIF
#
# LDAPv3
# base <dc=example,dc=com> with scope subtree
# filter: (userid=2)
# requesting: ALL
#

# example.com
dn: dc=example,dc=com
control:: IGZhbHNl   ----want to get rid of this in response
LastName: LastName
language: English
USERID: 2

# search result
search: 2
result: 0 Success

# numResponses: 2
# numEntries: 1
```

for this response generation we are passing control as empty in the following function call:-
clientConnection.sendSearchResultEntry(messageID, entry, controls);

and than the unboundid-ldapsdk is doing the rest of things.

so please provide your valuable research to this :)

Comment: I am lost as to what you are doing. Are you using ldapsearch or "clientConnection.sendSearchResultEntry(messageID, entry, controls);"?

Comment: yes..we are giving back response of LdapSearch in this case as no controls are passed in the ldapsearch request but if we supply the controls as empty than it will automatically set the control to some ocatal hexadecimal value than it is showing everytime the same value of control  IGZhbHN1 .....we want that this whole value not the parameter  the  Control with the value both should not come